# Running a Qt application at startup

Tags: linux, qt, scripting, startup

I wrote a Qt application that is going to run on Linux. It supposed to run at startup.

It's supposed to run on every Linux- Suse, RedHat etc.

What script should I write and Where to put it?

I don't know how to write scripts at all, so I would appreciate it if you will attach an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a desktop entry file for your application (see [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/)) and to put it in user's `$HOME/.config/autostart` directory.

Any desktop entry file in that dir will get executed when a Window Manager starts up (see [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html)).

To do this, usually you'll need to create your desktop entry file by hand (that's it, not via C++ code/script) and to just install in that directory via C++ code.

Comment: What path sould I specify? To which file- the pro? the exec of debug? of release?

Comment: Where? Inside the desktop entry file? In that file you need to put the path to your executable. If you look in `~/.config/autostart` (or if you look in some system dirs like `/usr/share/apps/`, you'll find plenty of desktop entry files to use as example)

Comment: OK. i made the entry file and it's working. but i still have a problem: it's supposed to read settings from an ini file but when it is launching on startup it fails to load the ini file. when i activate it manuali from the autostart folder- it succeeds. why? is it possible that it is still dudn't mount the file or something like this?

Comment: Where is your ini file, and how do you load it? If you use a relative path that's probably the reason: check your application's current working directory...

Comment: you are right that is the problem. but in the link u directed me to it says that what i set in entry in the path=... will be the cwd, or did i misunderstood?