# How to run a Qt application run at startup?

Tags: c++, qt, startup, qsettings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [running a qt application at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144222/running-a-qt-application-at-startup)

How can I run a qt program at startup so that the user won't see the desktop at all?
I am building my program in linux and I want to distribute it to linux users. 
I want to add that code to my app, because the customers don't have any understanding about linux.
I found that `QSettings` can do that, is it true? What about `QService`? Can we use a simple code like this?

```
QSettings  a;
A.setpath(IniFormat,SystemScope,/etc/xdg)
```

Comment: Can you clarify on "unable to see the desktop at all"? 
Do you mean that the computer will start and run your program instead a login manager? Or you need something else? Like preventing user to do some stuff?

Comment: i mean: a user log in and then my app run automatic and become full screen, (i know how to fullscreen)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `QSettings`. It is just a matter of making your app start in full screen, and placing it into a startup location on your system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QSettings has zero relevance to this and QService is for Symbian devices. In fact, your question has nothing to do with Qt.

What you need to do is place a *.desktop shortcut or link to the application in the user's startup folder. See:

http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html.

For example, if I want to start the application `/opt/myapp/myapp_executable` at login, I would create a `myapp.desktop` file with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/opt/myapp/myapp_executable
```

and put it in my ~/.config/autostart directory.

If you want it to be executed for every user at login, then you'd put it in /etc/xdg/autostart/. But again, check the XDG site because the directory can be different if an XDG environment variable is set that overrides the default.

Your question really belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: I'd rather suggest to pretend as a window manager/DE, so there will be no desktop at all.

Comment: @DmitryMelnikov It doesn't look like the OP would know how to write such an app (if he knew, he probably wouldn't have asked the question.) It's a Qt app, so most probably it depends on a running desktop with all its daemons and services (Window manager, D-Bus, Phonon, Gnome-keyring, etc.)

Comment: ok, but if i build my app, and give it to my friend, so he put app in another directory , so how can i handle that? he doesn't know anything about linux, he just want to start exacutabl

Comment: @ErfanTavakoli Then you should offer either an installer, or a package (*.deb, *.rpm, or whatever this specific Linux distro uses) that sets this up correctly. This isn't any different from Windows, really.

Comment: i go to the ~/.config/ but there isn't any folder with name "autostart" then i make a folder with this name and copy my .desktop file to it . but my app never run in startup. what is the problem.

Comment: @ErfanTavakoli Check the XDG docs and see if a variable is defined, and also check the docs of your desktop (is it Gnome?)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linux, use `cron` to launch your program, add something like this to `crontab`:

```
@reboot /path/to/program
```

Or to launch it at user login, append `/path/to/program` to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: That won't work, because the desktop isn't running yet when cron executes it.

Comment: you can set cron to launch an `at` command to delay the launch, something like `at -f /path/to/program now + 1 hour`

Comment: It won't launch it at login time though. It's a kludge, at best.

Comment: @NikosC. sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, could you try to explain it some other way?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that cron cannot execute programs at XDM login time. Either it'll do it too early, or too late.

Comment: fair enough, didn't notice that