# Run QT GUI application on startup

Tags: user-interface, debian, embedded-linux, startup

I am working on BeagleBone Black(Debian 3.8.13 running on it). I want to run QT GUI application on startup(show GUI on screen just after login).

I am able to run console applications on startup by editing rc.local file in /etc/ directory and placing executable in /bin/ directory. But it didn't work for GUI applications.

I have searched for it also but couldn't make much out of it.

I want to know how it is to be done.

Comment: Not really a StackOverflow question; every DE has its way to start applications at login.

Comment: Got answer from link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030932/how-to-run-a-qt-application-run-at-startup?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Debian 12

```
Gnome Desktop >Applications > Utilities > Tweaks > Startup Applications > Add
```